# Java code to Insert data into Ms access..Shows no error when i run but it doesnt add new row to my table

Tags: java

```
package com.sample.works;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;`

public class OdbcAccessInsertRows {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Pname", "", "");

            PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into pilot(pname,pcountry,plocation) values(?,?,?)");
            Statement sta = con.createStatement();              
            pstmt.setString(1, "Tom");
            pstmt.setString(2, "USA");
            pstmt.setString(3, "California");

            int r = pstmt.executeUpdate();

              con.commit();
             pstmt.close();


            if (r >= 1) {
                System.out.println("data entered successfully");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have doubt in prepared statement but it isn't giving any error after executing. No exceptions.. no errors when i run.. just my DB isn't getting updated

Comment: Please put some effort into formatting your code - use the preview to check that it looks how you want it to look before submitting. (Hint: for blocks of code, you don't need backticks at all... just indent.) Now, you're not committing anywhere... perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: Your empty `catch` block hides any exceptions that happen. Don't do that. You'll never know what went wrong.

Comment: Yes, I would take Jesper's advice and at least uncomment `System.err.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());`

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow!  Since it is your first time posting here I highly recommend reading through these as pages:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer they are both fantastic resources to use when asking or answering questions and will help you get the best answers quickly.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry...it is my first post here..now i formatted it properly...please see it and help me... when i run..it isnt showing any error  neither in command prompt nor in eclipse...when i open my msaccess...row isnt inserted

Comment: No, you've broken the formatting that someone else had already done for you - you've put some text in the middle of the code for no reason. No, as I said before, you're not calling `commit()` anywhere. Is that deliberate? I don't see you putting auto-commit on...

Comment: @JonSkeet  i added con.commit();...nothing happened

Comment: @Syed_pasha: Where did you add it? Put that information in your question, along with fixing the exception handler. What value of `r` was returned? Why are you calling `createStatement` for a statement you're then not using?

Comment: @JonSkeet  i printed the value of `r` and it shows as `1`

Comment: You're calling `commit()` *after* you've closed the prepared statement. That sounds like a bad idea to me. Have you tried committing first?

Comment: @JonSkeet yeaaa.... i tried `con.commit` and next `pstm.close()` next...nothing... and IM USING MS ACCESS 2010

Answer (score 1):

> I have doubt in prepared statement but it isnt giving any error after executing.

Actually, it *could be* giving an error.  The problem is that you are *throwing away* all errors (apart from `Error` subclasses) in the following code.

```
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // System.err.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }
```

There are two bugs in the above:

- You have commented out the code that prints the error message.  (Duh!)
- You are catching `Exception`.  That is usually a bad idea, and *definitely* a bad idea here.  You should only catch the exceptions that 1) you are expecting, and 2) that you can handle properly.

---

The next thing to do is to print the value of `r`.  That should be `1` ... which is the number of rows that should be inserted.

Comment: i removed the comment...still nothing on cmd prompt nor in eclipse.... no error is showing up

Comment: Have you fixed the `catch (Exception ...` abomination yet?  (Just asking ...)

Comment: yeaaa...i fixed the catch block and as u said i printed the value of `r` and it showed it as `1`